# How do I input filler dates into my report?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a multi list box that then filters a query based on selection (Code below).

```
  Private Sub Command39_Click()

  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim varItem As Variant
  Dim strCriteria As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  Set db = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Productivity_WeeklyFinal")

      For Each varItem In Me!Combo.ItemsSelected

      strCriteria = strCriteria & [Forms]![ProductivityForm]![Combo].ItemData(varItem) & ", "

      Next varItem

      strSQL = "SELECT Info_ME_Employees.ID, gs_1_week_finalUnion.SampleID,
      gs_1_week_finalUnion.Operator, Format$([TestDate],'m/dd/yyyy') AS Test_Date,                  
      gs_1_week_finalUnion.Test FROM Info_ME_Employees INNER JOIN gs_1_week_finalUnion ON
      Info_ME_Employees.Full_Name = gs_1_week_finalUnion.Operator" & _
       " WHERE Info_ME_Employees.ID IN (" & strCriteria & " )AND gs_1_week_finalUnion.TestDate
      Between (Date()-7-Weekday(Date(),2)+1) And (Date()-Weekday(Date(),2)) " & _
        " ORDER BY gs_1_week_finalUnion.Operator"
      qdf.SQL = strSQL

      Set db = Nothing
      Set qdf = Nothing

  End Sub
```

which then filters my queries.
[image: query datasheet view]

I then make a report from those records which then groups the records by operator. 
[image: report view]

My question is how am I able to input filler dates in between those records in the query that the report is based off. If I join filler dates in the query with a null field for the field operator, it'll group the null values. Is there a VBA approach that can lead me to the right direction? thank you

Comment: please don't use images for data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining your original named query to a cross join query of all distinct operators and dates each based on your *Productivity_WeeklyFinal* query:

**Cross Join Query** *(returns all possible match pairs)*

```
SELECT o.Operator, d.Test_Date
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT Operator
   FROM Productivity_WeeklyFinal) o
,
  (SELECT DISTINCT [Test_Date]
   FROM Productivity_WeeklyFinal) d
```

**Final Query** *(use for report)*

```
SELECT cj.[Operator], cj.[Test_Date], p.ID, p.SampleID, p.Test 
FROM CrossJoinQuery cj
LEFT JOIN Productivity_WeeklyFinal p
  ON  p.[Operator] = cj.[Operator]
  AND p.[Test_Date] = cj.[Test_Date]
ORDER BY cj.[Operator], CDate(cj.[Test_Date]) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait! This led me exactly how I want the report to be displayed!

Comment: Excellent! Great to hear and glad to help!